# Mercurial: Command for status similar to qdiff?

Tags: mercurial, diff

You can use qdiff to see the differences between the repository and the changes you've made in your patch queue thus far (even with qrefreshed changes). Is there a similar command for status, so that you can see all the files that are modified, even once you have qrefreshed the changes to those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show you changes in the currently applied patch:

> $ hg status --change .

And this one will include changes also in your working dir:

> $ hg status --rev .^